# SetTransactionHandler for ObjectContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can one set the TransactionHandler for ObjectContext?

I am checking this example: [Handling of Transaction Commit Failures](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Handling%20of%20Transaction%20Commit%20Failures%20), but it only shows for DbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransactionHandler also works for ObjectContext. The only problem is that the code based configurations (DbConfiguration) are not evaluated before the first DbContext is instantiated.

Two possible workarounds

Dummy DbContext:

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetTransactionHandler(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, 
            () => new CommitFailureHandler());
    }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // instantiate DbContext to initialize code based configuration
    using (var db = new TestContext()) { }

    using (var db = new TransactionHandlerDemoEntities()) {
        var handler = db.TransactionHandler; // should be CommitFailureHandler

        db.AddToDemoTable(new DemoTable { Name = "TestEntiry1" });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Or DbConfiguration.Loaded event

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DbConfiguration.Loaded += DbConfiguration_Loaded;

    using (var db = new TransactionHandlerDemoEntities()) {
        var handler = db.TransactionHandler;

        db.AddToDemoTable(new DemoTable { Name = "TestEntiry1" });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

static void DbConfiguration_Loaded(object sender, DbConfigurationLoadedEventArgs e)
{
    e.AddDependencyResolver(new TransactionHandlerResolver(
        () => new CommitFailureHandler(),
        SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
        null),true);
}
```

TransactionHandlerDemoEntities is an ObjectContext.

Comment: What an idea to use a dummy DbContext! +1  Although I still think people should try to move to DbContext API as soon as they can (as I did myself recently in an application).

Comment: @GertArnold I totally agree. Move to DbContext if possible. If not, I personally would go for the DbConfiguration.Loaded event workaround ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is exclusively for `DbContext`. If you can, refactor your ObjectContext-based application into DbContext as soon as possible. I think that many more new features will appear that only work with the `DbContext` API. Maybe `ObjectContext` will even get deprecated as a public API some day.

You can [create a `DbContext` from an `ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220058%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), but I don't think that's of much help to you. The main problem is undoubtedly that the rest of the data logic currently expects `ObjectContext`.